# Need to setup ejabberd for API call

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I need to get response on this URL:

https://[host IP]:8088/api/admin

I tried so many different configs so you might see extra stuff commented out.

I can easily access the web page, the only issue is, I cannot call admin api from application. No response in this regard.

```
Here are logs and config
https://pastebin.com/42pSg9yN
```

This is an AWS instance with Ubunutu 16.04

I have tried following this stackoverflow Answer too and also followed the official DOC too.

[How to call ejabberd Administrator API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917079/how-to-call-ejabberd-administrator-api)

https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/simple-configuration/

If there is anything you need to get a better understanding, Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your configuration file have some conflicts.

Plus the REST endpoints for admin is "/api" not "/api/admin".

If you have just installed ejaberred, I'll suggest you to do a clean installation using the official linux installer (not apt-get).

The installer is interactive and will generate most of the configurations for you.

Thanks